# Asynchronous ReadFile in Delphi XE2

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, readfile

I'm writing a small PE file analyzer and I have to read the contents of the PE file. I'm doing this via the `ReadFile` function, as shown below:

```
function TMainForm.GetPEData(var filename: string) : boolean;
var
  hFile:   DWORD;
  IDH:     TImageDosHeader;
  INH:     TImageNtHeaders;
  ISH:     TImageSectionHeader;
  dwRead: DWORD;
  szBuff: array[0..7] of Char;
  i:      WORD;
  PE: TPEFile;
begin
  Result := False;
  PE := TPeFile.Create;
  if PE.LoadFromFile (filename) then  
    Form2.edEntryPoint.Text := IntToHex(PE.RvaToFileOffset(PE.AddressOfEntryPoint), 8);
  SplashScreen.sLabel1.Caption := 'PE File Loaded';
  hFile := CreateFile(PChar(filename), GENERIC_READ, 
                      FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, 
                      OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
    SplashScreen.sLabel1.Caption := 'Reading DOS File Headers...';
    ReadFile(hFile, IDH, 64, dwRead, nil);
    if IDH.e_magic = IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE then
    begin
      SetFilePointer(hFile, IDH._lfanew, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
      SplashScreen.sLabel1.Caption := 'Reading NT File Headers...';
      //Here is where the UI freezes while the file is read...
      ReadFile(hFile, INH, 248, dwRead, nil);
      if INH.Signature = IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE then
      begin
        Form2.edImageBase.Text := IntToHex(INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 8);
        Form2.edSizeOfImage.Text := IntToHex(INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 8);
        Form2.edLinkerVersion.Text := IntToStr(INH.OptionalHeader.MajorLinkerVersion) + '.' + 
              IntToStr(INH.OptionalHeader.MinorLinkerVersion);
        Form2.edFileAlignment.Text := IntToHex(INH.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment, 8);
        Form2.edSectionAlignment.Text := IntToHex(INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment, 8);
        Form2.edSubSystem.Text := IntToHex(INH.OptionalHeader.Subsystem, 4);
        Form2.edEPFilestamp.Text := IntToStr(INH.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp);
        Form2.edFileType.Text := GetPEFileType(PE.ImageNtHeaders.Signature);

        for i := 0 to INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
        begin
          SetFilePointer(hFile, IDH._lfanew + 248 + i * 40, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
          ReadFile(hFile, ISH, 40, dwRead, nil);
          CopyMemory(@szBuff[0], @ISH.Name[0], 8);

          with Form2.sListView1.Items.Add do
          begin
            Caption := ShortString(szBuff);
            SubItems.Add(IntToHex(ISH.VirtualAddress, 8));
            SubItems.Add(IntToHex(ISH.Misc.VirtualSize, 8));
            SubItems.Add(IntToHex(ISH.PointerToRawData, 8));
            SubItems.Add(IntToHex(ISH.SizeOfRawData, 8));
            SubItems.Add(IntToHex(ISH.Characteristics, 8));
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

The bad thing is that, depending on the size of the file, I noticed that the `ReadFile` would often lag - and it happens synchronously. In the meantime, the UI freezes and looks horribly wrong to the user, who would be tempted to terminate it. I have considered threading, but I just want to see if there is any way I can use `ReadFile` in asynchronous mode. If there isn't, I'll jump to threading, even if I'll have a lot to modify in my code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're reinventing the wheel here? Delphi versions prior to 2007 have a demo that dumps the PE information (don't have the demo name here, but will post it later), and the [JEDI Code Library](http://delphi-jedi.org) has an entire unit (`JclPEImage`) containing ready-to-use functions that do all this stuff for you. (There's even a PEViewer demo that displays everything  in a way very similar to `DependencyWalker`.) All of the code performs just fine on even very large executables (5 MB+) without any UI issues or lags.

Comment: Hey there, @KenWhite, I don't have any preferences on the implementation. Indeed, I excluded JEDI, because of the fact that one unit links to another and so on and this - IMHO - makes the whole project mere difficult to maintain than if I had a single function in place. I'll take a look at the old Delphi demos, I think I still have the disc with Delphi 7 around.

Comment: When I get to my home system, I'll find the demo name from D7 and post it in a comment here. `JCL` is better than `JVCL` about using unit after unit, because it's strictly code. It does add some other stuff, but in this case you're adding a single unit name to your uses clause to include `JclPEImage`, and calling simple functions from your code. It's not bad (although I agree the JVCL is annoyingly co-dependent on other units it contains).

Comment: Even the JCL is rather bad about coupling to other JCL units.

Comment: The demo name in D7 is `ResXPlor`, in the `$(DELPHI)\Demos` folder. There's a unit called `ExeImage` that I believe holds the code you're looking for, although I didn't examine it specifically. @WarrenP, I didn't say it wasn't bad; I said it wasn't *as bad* as JVCL. :-)

Comment: Found it, @KenWhite. I'll look into it and see what I can come up with to prevent the UI from freezing.

Comment: You can use async IO with ReadFile but it's a little tricky to do. A separate thread would be the alternative. But reading PE data should be very very quick.

Comment: I created a new project, copied everything in there, including the UI, re-compiled and it now works like a charm. I'm not sure what happened there. I also have no idea about how I should assign points for the answers here. Any clues from SO veterans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this cases I always read the whole file to the memory also I use the TFileStream class for easier manipulation.

It is simpler to have the whole file in memory and PE files are usually small.

```
  type
    TSections = array [0..0] of TImageSectionHeader;
    PSections = ^TSections;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS : TFileStream;
  fisier : PImageDosHeader;
  INH : PImageNtHeaders;
  ISH : PSections;
  i   : Word;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('fisierul_tau.exe',fmOpenRead);
  GetMem(fisier,FS.size); //Aloci memorie pentru fisier
  FS.Read(fisier^,FS.Size); // Il citesti;
  FS.Free;
  INH := PImageNtHeaders(DWORD(fisier) + DWORD(fisier^._lfanew));
  ISH := PSections(DWORD(INH) + SizeOf(TImageNtHeaders));
  for i := 0 to INH^.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
  begin
      ShowMessage(PAnsiChar(@ISH[i].Name[0]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think that's the best approach too. Although I fixed my issue, this seems to be the closest approach to my initial question. Thanks a whole bunch, especially for the descriptive comments :)

Answer (score 1):

> The ReadFile function reads data from a file, and starts at the
>   position that the file pointer indicates. You can use this function
>   for both synchronous and asynchronous operations.

It is possible to use ReadFile asynchronously but depending on your UI this may not be the best solution.  Do you want your users to do anything while they're waiting for the PE file to load?

If you want your users to wait but have confidence that your program didn't freeze you could add a progress bar or just update your SplashScreen.

```
for i := 0 to INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
begin
   SplashScreen.sLabel1.Caption := 'Reading section ' + IntToStr(i) + ' of ' + IntToStr(INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
   SplashScreen.sLabel1.Update; // see Ken Whites comment
   // Application.ProcessMessages;
   ...
end
```

Comment: No, I just want to wait for the file to process in a decent, non-blocking manner as far as the UI is concerned. The user doesn't have too much to do than wait for the result of the function. Processing the messages does not change anything, I've tried before posting here, as the major bottleneck appears to be the ReadFile function.

Comment: Don't use `Application.ProcessMessages`. Use `SplashScreen.sLabel1.Update`, which accomplishes the same thing (displays the new text) without the side effects of `ProcessMessages`. `ProcessMessages` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Processing messages, using either Application.ProcessMessages or  SplashScreen.sLabel1.Update as Ken suggested, will give your UI a chance to update its appearance.  I suggested doing it in the loop because I assume that is was is taking up all your time.  However, you could do every time you change SplashScreen.sLabel1.Caption.

Comment: If you are just calling Application.ProcessMessages without changing the UI nothing will happen.  Keep in mind, if you are doing this in an onclick handler, the button will stay clicked until the handler returns.

Comment: To my dismay, the form still does not update beyond 'Reading NT File Headers...'. It freezes for about 20 seconds or so, then it comes back as if nothing had happened. The issue occurs here: ReadFile(hFile, INH, 248, dwRead, nil); and that is why I was trying to figure out if there was a way to asynchronously read the file.

Comment: Reading 248 bytes should not take 20 seconds.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't pump the message queue in a timely fashion then your UI is sure to hang. Nothing in this answer pumps the queue.